# What's the need of $^{S}_{T}$ in $f^{S}_{T}:S\rightarrow T$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, notation

I'm reading Lang's Undergraduate Analysis:

In the chapter about mappings, he says that we should denote the set of arrival and the set of departure with the following notation:

$$f^{S}_{T}:S\rightarrow T$$

Isn't this notion of arrival and departure already obvious with the notation $f:S\rightarrow T$?

Comment: I've never seem the notation $f^{S}_{T}$ before, indeed the standard one is to just say $f: S \to T$ and write just $f$ after that.

Comment: Lang also say that in the book, he says that this notation is too clumsy for practical uses. But I wonder if there is a $f^{T}_{S}:S\rightarrow T$.

Comment: Strange to me !!

Comment: Perhaps is like in linear algebra. Some authors when introducing vector spaces denote the operations by $\oplus$ and $\odot$ to avoid confusing with the usual ones and forcing the student to understand these are totally different operations. Usually people study analysis after calculus, and in calculus there are books that simply say "take the function $f(x)$" without comment about starting and ending set. Probably Lang want to force the people to see that these sets are part of the definition of the function. Probably he'll throw this notation away after some time.

Comment: Do not take it too seriously...